# Vim. Usar opción matchpairs para saltar entre inicio y final de signos de interrogación

Tags: configuración, vim

Pues lo ya dicho, quiero saber como usar la opción matchpairs de vim para saltar entre signos de
interrogación.
Cuando lo hago con otros signos de puntuación funciona correctamente, por ejemplo cundo hago:

[image: Captura de vim]

Soy capaz de saltar entre la apertura y cierre de los signos de admiración con usando el signo % (porcentaje). Sin embargo, no sucede lo mismo cuando hago el mismo proceso con signos de interrogación mediante:

[image: Captura 2 de Vim]

El único resultado que obtendré será un apantallante y poco explicativo error relacionado con una función de vim que ha fallado en hallar la pareja del signo de interrogación correspondiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A primera vista, la fuente más probable de la función con errores es alguno de mis plugins por lo que he hecho una prueba remplazando mi .vimrc por un archivo vacío, lo cual sin embargo no ha funcionado y sigo recibiendo exactamente el mismo error por lo que queda descartado que el culpable sea uno de mis plugins personales.
No obstante sigue siendo probable que sea culpa de uno de los plugins que vim usa de forma predeterminada cuando se usa en modo no compatible. ¿Qué como los se? Basicamente por que si le digo a vim explicitamente que no carge ningún archivo de configuración mediante "vim -u NONE" el mentado problema desaparece. El problema es que de los plugins intregrados no se nada, ni siguiera sus nombres ubicaciones o finalidades (más allá de que se que hay uno para abrir y manejar directorios).

Por lo tanto las preguntas son: ¿Hay alguna forma sencilla de arreglar dicho problema (sin tener que editar los plugins por defecto?, ¿A qué se debe exactamente dicho problema, tiene que ver con el manejo de expresiones regulares (He probado escapar el signo de interrogación con un '\' y no ha funcionado)?, en caso de que no haya manera sencilla de arreglarlo: ¿Dónde se ubican los scripts que se cargan por defecto en vim para poder modificarlos? y ¿Cuál es el script que tiene más probabilidades de estar causando el problema?

Comment: Ante el desconocimiento, te diría que pruebes con [matchit](https://github.com/adelarsq/vim-matchit)... Sin embargo, esto no es una expresión regular, por más que internamente lo convierta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución usando el plugin matchit.vim tal como proponian sería esta:

```
autocmd! BufWinEnter,BufEnter *   if exists("b:match_words")               | 
                                \   let b:match_words=b:match_words.',¿:?' |
                                \ else                                     |
                                \   let b:match_words='¿:?'                |
                                \ endif
```

match_words es una cadena que contiene pares separados por comas por lo que al añadir algún patrón de pares a un grupo preexistente lo propio es poner una coma para separarlo del resto.